# Umbraco Custom Controllers, the basics

Tags: c#, umbraco

I am getting this error "the type or namespace name 'Umbraco' could not be found"

I am using it in a custom controller HomeController.cs which lives in root/controllers/HomeController.cs.

But I can not seem to find any Umbraco namespaces.

```
using Umbraco.Web;
using Umbraco.Web.Models;

namespace umbraco.umbraco.Controllers
{
public partial class HomeController : Umbraco.Web.Mvc.RenderMvcController
{

}
}
```

any help with the basic is greatly appreciated

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try renaming your namespace?

```
umbraco.umbraco.Controllers
```

to

```
YourProject.Controllers
```